# Cursorial Adaptations in Tentacled Quadrupeds

Tags: creature-design, evolution, anatomy

All animals in this world are derived from an anatomy involving a tetrapod-like foreleg with tentacle-like hindlegs. This means that the hindlegs are substantially weaker than the forelegs, especially in larger forms. The limbs have similar positions to that of tetrapods

In tetrapods, the hindlegs are generally stronger and more specialized in cursorial animals. However, these quadrupeds, due to their different anatomy, have weaker hindlegs, which would affect how the adaptations would happen

**How would these quadrupeds tend to adapt for cursoriality?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first thought was a [Sebulba-like creature](https://www.deviantart.com/jpizzle6298/art/Star-Wars-Sebulba-165858658) from the star-wars franchise (original artwork by [Terryl Whitlatch](http://www.cgchannel.com/2010/01/interview-with-terryl-whitlatch/) for the film-franchise) but then I realised that there was a different, perhaps more unusual option:

I give you the [Cebrennus Rechenbergi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cebrennus_rechenbergi), the Moroccan flick-flack spider. I shan't bother with a still picture as that wouldn't do it justice, but there's a short and to-the-point [video on You Tube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IJhTrPDUoxs) or [another here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=brh8Fv7Lw9M) if the first link breaks. They can move uphill at on 40 degree slope and achieve speeds of 2 metres per second - that's 100 times their body-length per second or in human terms over 400 Km per hour (250 miles per hour approx).

Their strange method of locomotion is to tumble head-over heels, your creature could do the same, rolling off the hind tentacles, then using the stronger front-limbs for the main spring effect, giving impetus to their forward motion. Then as they reach top-speed, they're just touching the ground with the tips of their limbs, seemingly spinning along just above the ground.

For this to be effective, their limbs would need to be proportionally longer than their body as per the spider and they'd have well-developed [deltoid muscles](https://www.physio-pedia.com/Deltoid) for the spring effect.